# Azure build pipeline reports cannot read password

Tags: azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

my main.tf file looks like below

```
module "sql_vms" {
  source                  = "git::https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com/sampleuser/my_code/_git/terraform_modules.git//compute"
  rg_name                 = var.resource_group_name
  location                = module.resource_group.external_rg_location
  vnet_name               = var.virtual_network_name
  subnet_name             = var.sql_subnet_name
  app_nsg                 = var.application_nsg
  vm_count                = var.count_vm
  base_hostname           = var.sql_host_basename
  sto_acc_suffix          = var.storage_account_suffix
  vm_size                 = var.virtual_machine_size
  vm_publisher            = var.virtual_machine_image_publisher
  vm_offer                = var.virtual_machine_image_offer
  vm_sku                  = var.virtual_machine_image_sku
  vm_img_version          = var.virtual_machine_image_version
  username                = var.username
  password                = var.password
}
```

The modules are in same repo, technically not right but for now, I want to use the Azure repo which has a terraform module and creates multiple VM's from TF modules.

I get the error like below

```
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1439274Z [command]/usr/local/bin/terraform init -backend-config=storage_account_name=stoaccautomationnonprod -backend-config=container_name=stoacccon01nonprod -backend-config=key=nonprod.tfstate -backend-config=resource_group_name=automation -backend-config=arm_subscription_id=cc800481-b728-4d8f-81be-e80b955d346e -backend-config=arm_tenant_id=*** -backend-config=arm_client_id=*** -backend-config=arm_client_secret=***
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1441494Z [0m[1mInitializing modules...[0m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1442513Z Downloading git::https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com/sampleuser/my_code/_git/terraform_modules.git for sql_vms...
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1443347Z [31m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1444113Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mFailed to download module[0m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1444608Z 
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1445408Z [0mCould not download module "sql_vms" (main.tf:1) source code from
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1446189Z "git::https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com/sampleuser/my_code/_git/terraform_modules.git":
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1446845Z error downloading
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1447746Z 'https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com/sampleuser/my_code/_git/terraform_modules.git':
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1448669Z /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/sql_vms'...
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1449408Z fatal: could not read Password for
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1450157Z 'https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com':
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1450684Z terminal prompts disabled
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1450936Z 
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1451324Z [0m[0m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1451716Z [31m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1452230Z [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mFailed to download module[0m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1452525Z 
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1453109Z [0mCould not download module "sql_vms" (main.tf:1) source code from
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1454386Z "git::https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com/sampleuser/my_code/_git/terraform_modules.git":
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1454903Z error downloading
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1456723Z 'https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com/sampleuser/my_code/_git/terraform_modules.git':
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1457540Z /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/sql_vms'...
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1458063Z fatal: could not read Password for
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1458813Z 'https://iuclk3yjmv7qgglu3igkgxffacc2pzsv7nyhs44wmsjnrvccctaq@dev.azure.com':
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1459301Z terminal prompts disabled
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1459470Z 
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1459765Z [0m[0m
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1459896Z 
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1496541Z ##[error]Terraform command 'init' failed with exit code '1'.:  Failed to download module |  Failed to download module
2020-08-23T02:27:38.1786437Z ##[section]Finishing: terraform init
```

I was thinking to use SSH instead of HTTPS with PAT Token, unfortunately I couldn't figure it out how to add public key on Microsoft agent?

Please assist

Comment: Do you try it and does it solve your problem? Please let me know if there is anything you do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the SSH key to pull the Terraform modules, you need to generate the SSH key yourself. And then create an SSH Key in the DevOps:

[image]

And then you need to upload the private key in the pipeline variable group as secure files and add the step to install the SSH in your agent. The Install SSH in an agent job like this:

[image]

Get more details about [use SSH to pull the remote Terraform module](https://samcogan.com/using-terraform-modules-from-git-in-azure-devops/).